# Как получить значение из колонок базы данных?

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite

Есть база данных, создал запрос, который возвращает одну строку с 12 колонками:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE _id = "+id;
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

Как теперь можно данные из этих 12 колонок занести в массив?

Comment: Для работы с данными, полученными из БД используется класс [`Cursor`](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/cursor.php), который позволяет читать полученную информацию, перемещать указатель на текущий элемент и некоторые другие. Для полноценной работы желательно ознакомиться со всеми [его методами](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#pubmethods).

Answer (score 3):

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String columnName : cursor.getColumnNames()) {
        values.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName))); 
    }

    for (String value : values) {        
        Log.d("TAG", value);
    }
}
```